# How to hide the url ip to sub domain name

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to this. I want to hide ip address/~foldername/ url to domain name url, so that the address in the url changes to new url but it should point to the same destination folder ?
need assistance

Thank you

Comment: please give examples. What's your "input" and what's your desired "output"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a rewrite rule on `www.domain.com/folder` to redirect to `example.domain.com` (this is your new url change if you want another). Then set up example.domain.com to either lie about who and where it is, or fix all links in pages on example.domain.com to `explicitly go to` http://www.domain.com/folder.

In the root .htaccess file on www.domain.com: (to redirect to the subdomain)

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*) http://example.domain.com/$1 [R, L]
```